# Appending a character to a PHP output

Tags: php

I have a simple question.

```
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['Rep'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
```

Assume that the above snippet outputs "1". How can I append a dot `.` in front of it in the above code? So that the output will be `.1` instead of `1` only. I couldn't find a similar example on the web, so I decided to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: So you mean `echo "<td>." . $row['Rep'] . "</td>";`

Comment: Or `echo "<td>" . '.' . $row['Rep'] . "</td>"; `

Comment: I mean the echo will include a dot in front of the output values.

Comment: Will it always start with "."? Could it ever start with "0.", or be a whole number?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . "." . $row['Rep'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
```

or in case it's not 1

```
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . ($row['Rep'] == 1 ? "." . $row['Rep'] : $row['Rep']) . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like

`echo '<tr><td>.' . $row['Rep'] . '</td></tr>';`